# Can I use admob interstitial ad instead of reward ad?

Tags: android, mobile, admob, policy

Currently I'm making a game for android and admob's reward video ads and interstitial ads are being implemented. Once the game is over the player can play from current state by watching reward video like other games. But when the game is over I want to make two options for player.
(1) Continue play by watching reward video ad.
(2) Continue play by showing the interstitial ad.
For (2), is it legal to show interstitial ad to give reward to user? I also checked [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en). But it doesn't say anything about using interstitial as reward ad. So, can I use interstitial ad to give reward to the player?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Interstitial Ad can be used to reward the users. There are no issues with that. If you are confused with implementation or on the policy and the best practices, refer the following article -

https://medium.com/@varundwarkani10/how-to-use-google-admob-effectively-in-android-applications-dcbbb6df930b?source=friends_link&sk=2a5bfbdcd73c17b546cf559da28b62e8

Answer (score 1):

I have read almost all Admob policy and I have found nothing that prohibits this special case.
However, please let us know have you finally got any issue when using this special approach based on rewarding user using an Interstitial ad?
I plan to do something similar and I am interested to know if that cause no issue to do so!

Comment: I haven't got any problem yet. So, I think you can also do the same thing without any Admob policy issues. But always remember to check again their policy before you submit your work to the store because the policies are always updating.